# Bind Element/Association/Aggregation in JS view using JSON notations

Tags: sapui5

With reference to the ["Payroll Control Center Mockup" post](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2014/02/16/mocking-up-the-payroll-control-center-fiori-app), how do you bind elements to UI Controls in JS views rather than XML, using JSON Notation?

Here is a snapshot of the XML view

```
<IconTabFilter  
    binding="{/cities/0}"  
    text="{name} ({id})"  
    icon="sap-icon://group"  
    design="Horizontal">  
</IconTabFilter>
```

I was trying to do the same in JS views but could not get it to work

```
new sap.m.IconTabFilter({  
    bindElement:'{/cities/1}',  
    icon: "sap-icon://notes",  
    text:"{/name}",  
    //text:  
    count: "12",  
    color:sap.ui.core.IconColor.Critical,  
    content: new sap.m.Text({  
        text: "Notes go here ..."  
    })  
}),
```

I have specified ComplexBinding in the index.html, also tried various options e.g.

```
association:'{/cities/1}',

aBindings:'{/cities/1}',
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can use `binding` as an XML attribute, you can't use `bindElement` in the same way when you're defining controls in JavaScript. `bindElement` is a method rather than a property. So this is one way to do it:

```
var aIconTabFilters = [0,1].map(function(n) {
    var oITF = new sap.m.IconTabFilter({
        text: "{name} ({id})",
        icon: "sap-icon://group",
        design: "Horizontal"
    });
    oITF.bindElement("/cities/"+n);
    return oITF;
});
```

Note that `bindElement` is being called explicitly.

I've [re-written the mockup using a JavaScript view in a different branch of the repo](https://github.com/qmacro/sapui5bin/blob/payrolljs/SinglePageExamples/PayrollControlCenterMockup.html) so you can see it in context and compare it with the [original XML view version here](https://github.com/qmacro/sapui5bin/blob/master/SinglePageExamples/PayrollControlCenterMockup.html).